# 'confer an equitable right on B to compel fulfilment of the promise'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

[*O'Sullivan & Hilliard's The Law of Contract*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/OSullivan-Hilliards-Law-Contract-Janet/dp/0198807821/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) (2018 8 ed). p 115.

> 5.79 First, there must be a clear and unambiguous promise or representation that the creditor
>   will not insist on his strict legal rights, satisfying an equivalent test of certainty as
>   is required for contractual obligations (see *Baird Textiles v Marks & Spencer plc* (2002)
>   discussed at paras 3.15–3.18, and *BMIC Limited v Chinnakannan Sivasankaran, Siva
>   Limited* (2014)). This requirement is not surprising—it is unacceptable to deprive a party
>   of a legal right unless, judged objectively, this was the only plausible interpretation of his
>   words or conduct. More important is the requirement that the promise must relate to
>   existing legal rights, a significant limitation because it means there must be an existing
>   legal relationship between the parties. Promissory estoppel cannot take the place of consideration
>   when a contract is being formed for the first time between the parties, only (as
>   in the *Foakes v Beer* problem) when existing contractual rights are being varied. Denning
>   J did not emphasise this restriction in *High Trees* (although, of course, the landlord’s
>   representation there was as to existing legal rights—the right to claim the full rent) but
>   it has been applied ever since. Brennan J regarded this restriction as ‘illogical’ in *Walton
>   Stores v Maher* (see para 5.94): ‘If a promise by A not to enforce an existing right against
>   B **[1.] is to confer an equitable right on B to compel fulfilment of the promise**, why should
>   **[2.]B be  denied the same protection in similar circumstances if the promise is intended to
>   create in B a new legal right against A**?’

Please ELI5 the bolded phrases.

1. Once 'an equitable right' is conferred 'on B', who's compelling the fulfilment? Who's the promisee ?
2. Why would "B be  denied the same protection in similar circumstances if the promise is intended to
   create in B a new legal right against A"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your question #1:

Equitable rights are the rights an entity has by virtue of an overarching sense of "The Just Thing" as distinct from rights explicitly granted by an agreement.

If A promises B that A will not enforce some right that A has under an existing agreement between them, B receives a right to compel A to honor or fulfill that promise; but unless there had been a *quid pro quo* for that promise, B's right to compel A to fulfill the promise is not obtained contractually but by equity.

#### Your question #2.

Brennan is saying that in a new agreement with B, A ought to be able to promise not to enforce a right that A already has, i.e. a pre-existing right unrelated to any agreement between them, and that B should receive an equitable right to compel A to fulfill that promise. By restricting estoppel to existing contracts, B is being denied the opportunity to enter into a new agreement with A in which A would promise not to enforce some right A has, whereby B in turn would obtain an equitable right to compel A to fulfill the promise. Brennan asks : why should B be denied that opportunity to rely upon equity? The restriction which limits estoppel to existing agreements forces B to offer A some consideration in return for A's promise if B wants that promise as part of a new agreement. As a result, B's right to compel A to honor its promise would not be founded in equity but in contract law.

Disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer, but I've been swindled by a few of them.

P.S. Consider the verb *sound* which has a legal definition (see #19) here:
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sound

Answer (score 0):

What Brennan J objects to is the doctrine that

> Promissory estoppel cannot take the place of consideration when a contract is being formed for the first time between the parties, *only [...] when **existing** contractual rights are being varied.*

Brennan J regards this as illogical.

- Primary estoppel arises when A promises not to enforce an **existing** right—A's right under an existing contract. In this case B acts subsequently in reliance on that promise; consequently, B has the right to compel A to fulfil that promise.
- But if that is the case, why should B **not** have the same right ('Why should B be denied the same protection') when A makes a similar promise with respect to a **new** contract? A promise is a promise, whenever it is made; why does B lose that equitable right when a new contract is being written?